# Find the smallest value in a matrix using Python (without using the inbuilt min function)

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x, matrix

Given an matrix of :

```
matrix = {
    "A": ['-' , 6   , '-' , 4   , '-' , '-' ],
    "B": [6   , '-' , 1   , 3   , 8   , 2   ],
    "C": ['-' , 1   , '-' , '-' , '-' , 3   ],
    "D": [4   , 3   , '-' , '-' , 4   , '-' ],
    "E": ['-' , 8   , '-' , 4   , '-' , 4   ],
    "F": ['-' , 2   , 3   , 4   , 4   , '-' ]
}
```

How would one go about finding the smallest value?

I would like to use something other than the `min()` function as I would like to
use something that would transfer over to other languages as well.

Comment: this is a `dictionary`, not `matrix`

Comment: Loop over all the values and keep track of what is the smallest number and update it every time you find a new, smaller, number

Comment: Other languages have min as well.  Anything you write in one language would have to be adapted to another language.  More explicitly: if you write a python program using min, you can translate it to other languages; and if you write a python program without min, it would still need translating to "transfer over to other languages" (whatever that means).  The only reason I can think of to not use min is if your homework says "don't use min".

Comment: @Teepeemm hmm fair. The reason was that I didn't want to learn something python specific but rather the mechanics of how to do it. I thought the 'transfer over to other languages' part kinda surmised that point but whatever.

Comment: @baxx: Is there still something missing? Please let me know if you need any further explanation!

Answer (score 1):

Remember this is a `dictionary`, not a `matrix`. You loop through every values and save all the time the minimum one.

```
dict = {"A": ['-' , 6   , '-' , 4   , '-' , '-' ],
          "B": [6   , '-' , 1   , 3   , 8   , 2   ],
          "C": ['-' , 1   , '-' , '-' , '-' , 3   ],
          "D": [4   , 3   , '-' , '-' , 4   , '-' ],
          "E": ['-' , 8   , '-' , 4   , '-' , 4   ],
          "F": ['-' , 2   , 3   , 4   , 4   , '-' ]
}

min = 1337133713371337
for i in dict.values():
    for m in i:
        if m < min:
            min = m
print min
```

Comment: What if the 'matrix' contains only numbers greater than `100000000`? We can keep doing this ;-)

Comment: @TimCastelijns yes this was a concern of mine when I had a go at it earlier.... I guess one could use `sys.maxint()` (or whatever it is) but I thought that there might be a better way or something.... I'm not sure though maybe it's needed ?

Comment: @TimCastelijns There's a decent mathematical argument that the minimum value of an empty list is `float('inf')`.  But comparison won't work for the non-numeric entries.

Answer (score 1):

This is a Python 2 solution (doesn't work for Python 3):

```
d = []
for x in matrix.values():
    d.extend(x)
d = list(filter(lambda x: isinstance(x, int), d))
min = d[0]
for m in d:
    if m < min:
        min = m
```

Comment: The "list" command is not necessary since "filter" returns a list (see also my answer below).

Comment: In `Python 2.7` returns list, in `Python 3.x` returns generator. The question is about `Python 3.x`

Comment: Oh, overlooked the Python 3 tag; then you are right.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an one-liner for it:

```
from itertools import chain
print sorted(filter(lambda x: isinstance(x, (int, long, float)), chain.from_iterable(matrix.values())))[0]
```

What is going on?

As it has been pointed out, you have a dictionary, not a matrix; the values you can access by using `matrix.values()`. Then you flatten the resulting list of lists using `itertools.chain`, `filter` out all numbers, sort the numbers and print the first one.

If you want to avoid sorting, you could also do the following:

```
from itertools import chain
newL = filter(lambda x: isinstance(x, (int, long, float)), chain.from_iterable(matrix.values()))
# [6, 4, 1, 3, 6, 1, 3, 8, 2, 8, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 4]
minVal = newL[0]
for val in newL:
    if val < minVal:
        minVal = val
```

Answer (score 0):

```
matrix['A'].sort()
```

`matrix['A'][0] #this is the smallest value`

```
for each in matrix:
    matrix[each].short()
    matrix[each][0]
```

Comment: then the matrix would be out of order - which would be tricky to use in the algorithm that I was planning on using it with i think (prims). Also I feel that `sort()` might introduce something that's tricky to transer to other languages. Cheers tho

Comment: Doing a sort when you only need the minimum isn't very efficient. Apart from needing to copy the original data if you don't want to mess up its order, sorting is O(nlogn) at best (or O(n²) if you use a naive sorting algorithm), whereas finding the minimum by simple looping is O(n).

Comment: This gets the min of row `A`, not the entire thing.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively if you have **numpy**:

```
# your dictionary
In [128]: matrix
Out[128]: 
{'A': ['-', 6, '-', 4, '-', '-'],
 'B': [6, '-', 1, 3, 8, 2],
 'C': ['-', 1, '-', '-', '-', 3],
 'D': [4, 3, '-', '-', 4, '-'],
 'E': ['-', 8, '-', 4, '-', 4],
 'F': ['-', 2, 3, 4, 4, '-']}

In [129]: import numpy as np

In [130]: m = np.array(list(matrix.values()))

In [131]: m
Out[131]: 
array([['-', '6', '-', '4', '-', '-'],
       ['4', '3', '-', '-', '4', '-'],
       ['-', '2', '3', '4', '4', '-'],
       ['-', '8', '-', '4', '-', '4'],
       ['-', '1', '-', '-', '-', '3'],
       ['6', '-', '1', '3', '8', '2']], 
      dtype='<U1')

# masking out '-' elements and find the min for their int type values
In [132]: m[np.where(m != '-')].astype(int).min()
Out[132]: 1
```

Comment: You're still using `min()`, just numpy's version of it.